# googleapis import fail with typescript/vue/firebase hosting

Tags: typescript, vue.js, google-api, firebase-hosting

In a single file vue component, importing `googleapis` via `require` fails with error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
at t.exports (index.js:75)
at Object.f447 (index.js:54)
at o (bootstrap:78)
at Object.d465 (jwtclient.js:26)
at o (bootstrap:78)
at Object.<anonymous> (googleauth.js:37)
at Object.0a40 (googleauth.js:640)
at o (bootstrap:78)
at Object.3ccc (index.js:18)
```

`googleapis` has been imported with

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
```

If it's imported with

```
import { google } from 'googleapis'
```

Then the same error will appear the first time this `google` import gets called

Help appreciated :)

Comment: Are you trying to run `googleapis` in a browser?  That won't work.  For browsers, you should use the ["JavaScript" client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) instead.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Thanks! I ended up moving that part of the functionality into Firebase function and used it from there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm google apis won't work in browser so I moved that part into firebase functions instead.